# combinar correspondencia Excel y PowerPoint dos Diapositivas vba

Tags: vba

**Tengo problemas al crear correspondencia Excel y PowerPoint dos Diapositivas, cuando ejecuto el código para una solo si reemplaza el contenido, cuando trato de ejecutar para dos diapositivas no funciona el código pueden ayudarme en observar donde esta el error**

```
Sub Combinar()
    Set objSld = objPres.Slides.Range(Array(1, 2)).Duplicate
    For Each objSld In objSld.Shapes.Range(Array(1, 2))
                   If objSld.HasTextFrame Then
                        If objSld.TextFrame.HasText Then
                            objSld.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<NOMBRE>", strNombre
                            objSld.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<CARGO>", strCargo
                            objSld.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<DNI>", strDNI
                            objSld.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<FOTO>", strFoto
                            objSld.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<fdemision>", strFechaIn
                            objSld.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<fdvencimiento>", strFechaVen
                       End If
                    End If
                Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: quiero llenar las dos diapositivas que duplique, desde una hoja de Excel

Set objSld = objPres.Slides.Range(Array(1, 2)).Duplicate

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [correspondencia Excel y PowerPoint dos Diapositivas VBA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/550429/correspondencia-excel-y-powerpoint-dos-diapositivas-vba)